# How can i handle null value by using JSonobject.getInt function?

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get values from Json object and I have a problem. I'm using getint function to get value but the value is null and getint function gving error.

How can I solve this problem?

Code :

```
firmInfo.setFirmID(object.getInt(Constants.FirmID));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assuming that `object` is of type `JSONObject` you can use

```
object.optInt(Constants.FirmID)
```

or

```
object.optInt(Constants.FirmID, defaultValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the object you recieve is an instanceof `JSONObject` before you try to `getInt()`. Also you need to check if null before passing as a `param` to your `getInt()`. Like below

```
if(Constants.FirmID != null){
 firmInfo.setFirmID(object.getInt(Integer.parseInt(Constants.FirmID)));
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-the-given-string-is-valid-json-or-not-in-java) link

Comment: No no no, Constants.FirmID isn't already null. getInt(Constants.FirmID) is getting value from Jsononject and the variable is FirmID.

{
   FirmID :null
}

like this.

Comment: ooh ok so the JSON object for FirmID is null ?, In that case you cannot getInt of null. Its a server side issue/bug. If you think the object firmid should contain integers fix the server to send you 0 instead of null ?

Answer (score -2):

`getint` gives error message if there is no such key in JSONObject or your error is while setting it to `firmInfo`

check whether the id is present or not using

```
object.has("Constants.FirmID")
```

if it has the key , check whether it is null or not

```
if(String.valueOf(jArray.getInt("sdfgh")) != null)
{
    // add your code here . . . . . 
}
```

or

```
if(String.valueOf(jArray.getInt("sdfgh")).length < 1)
    {
        // add your code here . . . . . 
    }
```