# Best practice to receive JSON and convert it to an object

Tags: java, android, json, json.net

I am receiving a JSON string in java, and I wish to convert it to an object that represents the string.
I currently have this function:

```
private ArrayList<MyDevice> parseResposne(String response) {
    ArrayList<MyDevice> devices = null;
    JSONArray jsnArr = null;
    try {
        // JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        jsnArr = new JSONArray(response);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < jsnArr.length(); i++) {
         MyDevice tmpDevice = new MyDevice(jsnArr.);
        // devices.add(tmpDevice);
    }

    return null;
}
```

here is my Mydevice class:

```
public class MyDevice {

public String name;
public int deviceId;
public String serialNo;
public String deviceType;
public boolean enabled;

public MyDevice(int deviceId, String name, String serialNo, String deviceType, boolean enabled) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
    this.name = name;
    this.serialNo = serialNo;
    this.deviceType = deviceType;
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
}
```

is there not an easier way such as the model binder ins asp.net mvc?

What is the standard / best way to convert json to an object?

Comment: there is no standard way. You have to parse the json accordingly to the backends's response

Comment: You should look GSON up.  https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Google's [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for easy conversion of json to Object and vice versa.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<MyDevice> yourArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<MyDevice>>(){}.getType());


public class MyDevice {

    public String name;
    public int deviceId;
    public String serialNo;
    public String deviceType;
    public boolean enabled;

   //Setters and Getters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complicated json or a considerable amount of data, you may be better off using Gson to map data and your model classes. Eg.:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ModelClass modelClass= new ModelClass();
    modelClass= gson.fromJson(responseContent,ModelClass.class); 
//where responseContent is your jsonString
    Log.i("Web service response", ""+modelClass.toString());
```

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

For Naming discrepancies(according to the variables in webservice), can use annotations like 
`@SerializedName`. (So no need to use `Serializable`)

Comment: One thing worth noting about Gson is how badly it treats invalid JSON documents - often, it'll attempt to parse them without any warning. Changing this behaviour can be quite cumbersome.

Comment: @kamituel if the JSON is invalid, the effort of handling it would be quite similar i think, irrespective of the method :) . i'd think it is not a "parser"'s responsibility to validate the JSON though does Jackson or any other library provide invalid json handling?

Comment: I'd prefer if parser would (at least) be able to throw an error when feeded with string which is not a JSON document.

Comment: in case you want to try a solution, you can manually validate the json by checking if its a JSONObject or com.google.gson.JsonElement, before feeding it to a parser

Comment: But then I'd effectively parse the same document twice. My point is that parsing library should at least warn that input wasn't valid.

Comment: ...though does Jackson or any other library provide invalid json handling?

Comment: @kamituel Relevant solution elsewhere, including a quick n' dirty method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22859985

Answer (score 0):

You can look at streaming parser such as GSON/Jackson etc.

Comment: this should be comment!