# trailing characters getting parsed in json

Tags: java, json

I am trying to check if json is valid and I am experiencing a bizzare behaviour.
When I append some characters to a parsable json both jackson and gson are parsing it and they ignore the trailing charaters. I want to check if the json is strictly valid. Please help. I tried a couple of flags in `mapper.configure()` but I couldn't find the exact setting.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JSONUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonStr = "{\"outputValueSchemaFormat\": \"\",\"sortByIndexInRecord\": 0,\"sortOrder\":\"descending\"}opdfahf";
        System.out.println(JSONUtil.isValidJson(jsonStr));
    }
    public static boolean isValidJson(String str) {
        try {
             final ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
             mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
             mapper.readTree(str);
         System.out.println(str);
             new JsonParser().parse(str);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
            return true;
        }
}
```

PS: This question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-a-given-string-is-valid-json-in-java) because i have used the same code but it seems that either the library has some bug or some configuration flag is missing. I tried a couple of configuration flag but none seems to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a given string is valid JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-a-given-string-is-valid-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on the forums i found an interesting link someone who had the same problem. The response from the team was

> Yes. This is by design. If you want to catch such problems, you need to construct JsonParser, advance it manually. Existence of multiple root-level values is not considered a validity problem, but in your case, end-of-stream without matching ']' would be caught.

Please refer to the problem [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/726)

For solution refer [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-jsonparser.html)

Answer (score 1):

Real world parsers consideres as a feature to accept incorrect JSON *provided they can understand it*. Among errors that they can easily fix (not all parsers do all, but some can fix some):

- unquoted identifiers => an identifier should be there with or without quotes
- single quotes instead of double quotes => trivial to fix
- trailing characters => the parser can detect the end of the Json string and can ignore whatever comes after
- ...

TL/DR: a parser is required to accept valid Json, it is simply unspecified what it does with incorrect but understandable data...

IMHO, if you want to strictly validate a Json string, you should build *by hand* a custom validator controling the syntax given at http://json.org/, or even better the [ECMA-404 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ecma-st/ECMA-262.pdf).