# Spring MVC Override Received Content Type

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring MVC application and have a client that I have no control over.  This client is POSTing JSON data but transmitting a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header.  Spring naturally trusts this header and tries to receive the data but can't because its JSON. Has anyone had experience overriding the header that Spring receives or just specifying exactly what type of data is coming, regardless of the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things;

1. Change the client to send the `Content-Type:
   application/json` header
2. Write a Servlet Filter or Spring Interceptor which is on top of the Spring Controller and checks for the header `Content-Type`. If it is not `application/json` then it changes it to `application/json`.

Comment: 3. Read the payload manually, by adding parameter of type `HttpServletRequest`, or `Reader`, or `InputStream`, or `@RequestBody String`, or ...

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going the `@RequestBody String` route as it fit my use case best!

Comment: I have tried to go with suggestion 2. But the HttpServletRequest is not mutable when it comes to headers and I tried to wrap it in one of mine and override the header but still. Any examples on how to do 2?

Comment: You also need to override HttpServletRequest and a whole lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a separate controller to handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests. If the request is a valid JSON, then you can parse it and forward it to to appropriate service.

This way you can also handle a case in future where you get request of same type which is not a valid JSON.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/handleURLEncoded", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Object handleURLEncoded(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
    String json = httpEntity.getBody();
    //now you have your request as a String
    //you can manipulate it in any way

    if(isJSONValid(json)) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        //forward request or call service directly from here
        //...
    }

    //other cases where it's not a valid JSON
}
```

*Note: `isJSONValid()` method copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10174938/2815219) answer*