# error -org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am making an app for generating otp so i have used php and my sql. WAMP as a local host provider. My log cat file contains

```
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at com.techrefic.app1611.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:178)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at com.techrefic.app1611.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:172)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-18 13:27:23.766 30362-30362/com.techrefic.app1611 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-18 13:27:23.776 1620-1943/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@7b87dab attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@ba60539
11-18 13:27:26.741 1317-1603/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 5574322 , only wrote 5436064
11-18 13:28:00.085 1212-1272/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 84 syncs in 60s
11-18 13:29:00.061 1212-1272/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 4 syncs in 60s
```

xml file activity_main.xml contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.techrefic.app1611.MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Mobile Number"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/linkLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Already have an account? Login here"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

dialog_confirm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="48dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter OTP"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextOtp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonConfirm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Confirm Otp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my java files are 1. MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

      //    Creating views
      private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private EditText editTextPhone;
    private EditText editTextConfirmOtp;

    private AppCompatButton buttonRegister;
    private AppCompatButton buttonConfirm;

    //Volley RequestQueue
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    //String variables to hold email, password and phone number
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String phone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);

        buttonRegister = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

       //Initializing the RequestQueue
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

       //Adding a listener to button
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    }

//    This method would confirm the OTP

    private void confirmOtp() throws JSONException {

        //Creating a Layout Inflater object for the dialog box
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        //Creating a view to get the dialog box

        View confirmDialog = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirm, null);

//        Initialing confirm button for dialog box and edittext of dialog box

        buttonConfirm = (AppCompatButton) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonConfirm);
        editTextConfirmOtp = (EditText) confirmDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextOtp);

        //Creating an alert dialog builder
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        //Adding our dialog box to the view of alert dialog
        alert.setView(confirmDialog);

        //Creating an alert dialog
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

        //Displaying the alert dialog
        alertDialog.show();

//        Onclick of the confirm button from alert dialog
        buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Hiding the alert dialog
                alertDialog.dismiss();

                //Displaying a progressbar
                final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Authenticating ", "Please wait while we check the entered code", false, false);

                //Getting the user entered otp from edittext
                final String otp = editTextConfirmOtp.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating an string request
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.CONFIRM_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                                    loading.dismiss();

                                    //Start a new activity
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Success.class));
                                } else {
                                    //Displaying a toast if the otp entered is wrong
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong OTP Please try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    try {
                                        //Asking user to enter otp again
                                        confirmOtp();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                             }
                        }){

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        //Adding the parameters otp and email

                        params.put(Config.KEY_OTP, otp);
                        params.put(Config.KEY_USERNAME, username);
                        return  params;
                    }
                };
                //Adding the request to the queue
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });
    }


    //this method will get register the user
    private void register() {
        //Displaying a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Registering", "Please wait...", false, false);

        //Getting user data
        username = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString().trim();

        //Again creating the request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        try {
                            //Creating the json object from the response
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                            //IF it is success
                            if (jsonResponse.getString(Config.TAG_RESPONSE).equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                                //Asking user to confirm otp
                                confirmOtp();
                            } else {
                                //If not successful user may already have registerd
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or Phone Number already registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding the params to the request
                params.put(Config.KEY_USERNAME, username);
                params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);
                params.put(Config.KEY_PHONE, phone);
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //calling refgister method on register button click
        register();
    }
}
```

And Config.java

```
public class Config {

    public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.0.4/famous/register.php";
    public static final String CONFIRM_URL = "http://192.168.0.4/famous/confirm.php";

    //Keys to send username, password, phone and otp
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_OTP = "otp";

    //JSON Tag from response from server
    public static final String TAG_RESPONSE= "ErrorMessage";
}
```

my gradle file contains dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

and php files i used register.php

```
<?php
// Constants for our API
// this is applicable only when you are using SMS API
define('SMSUSER', $_POST[username]);
define('PASSWORD', $_POST[password]);
define('PHONE', $_POST[phone]);
// define('SENDERID', 'EDCRTZ');

// This function will send the otp


$otp = int rand(100000, 999999);

    // This is the sms text that will be sent via sms
$sms_content = "Welcome ".SMSUSER.", to DEMO Tp RTA app: Your verification code is".$otp ;

// This is the Actual API URL concatnated with required values
     $api_url ="http://mymessageapi".$sms_content."&senderId=EDCRTZ&routeId=1&mobileNos=".PHONE."&smsContentType=english";


//Envoking the API url and getting the response
$response = file_get_contents($api_url);

//Returning the response
return $response;

//If a past request comes to this script
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
// getting username password and phone number
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

//Generating a 6 digits OTP or verification code
$otp = rand(100000, 999999);


    //Importing the db connection script

require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Creating an SQL Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO famous (username, password, phone, otp) values('$username','$password','$phone','$otp')";

//If the query executed on the db successfully 
if (mysql_query($con,$sql)) {
    // printing the failure message in json
echo '{"ErrorMessage":"Failure"}';   
}
//Closing the databse connection
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

confirm.php

```
<?php

//If a post request is detected 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    //gETTING THE username and otp
$username = $_POST['username'];
$otp = $_POST['otp'];


// Importing the dbConnect script
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Creating an SQL to fetch the otp from the table
$sql = "SELECT otp FROM test-table WHERE username = '$username'";

//Getting the result array from databse 
$result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

//Getting the otp from the array 
 $realotp = $result['otp'];

//Getting the otp given is equal to otp fetched from database
if ($otp == $realotp) {
// Creating an sql query to update the column verified to 1 for the specified user

$sql = "UPDATE test-table SET verified= '1' WHERE username ='$username'";

//If the table is updated
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        //displaying failure
echo 'success'; 
}else{
    //displaying failure
    echo "failure";
}
}else{
    //displaying failure if otp is not equal to the otp fetched from databse
    echo 'failure';
}   
//Closing the database
mysql_close($con);

}
?>
```

dbConnect.php file

```
<?php
 define('HOST', 'localhost');
 define('USER', 'root');
 define('PASS', '');
 define('DB', 'famous');

 //connecting to database
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
 ?>
```

i used my wamp for localhost server to run my app localy with my app on same ip address any one who can solve this problem

Comment: `<br` looks like the beginning of **XML** data, not JSON. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/, e.g. as suggested by others: Look at the actual value of the string being parsed (`response`).

Answer (score 2):

In `JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response)`,
you are creating a json object from the response, which is not a valid JSON.

Try looking at `response` value in debug mode to figure out what's there, and how to get the actual JSON you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing string in php instead of it echo json object

Change your confirm.php code

```
//If the table is updated
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        //displaying failure
echo 'success'; 
}else{
    //displaying failure
    echo "failure";
}
}else{
    //displaying failure if otp is not equal to the otp fetched from databse
    echo 'failure';
}
```

to

```
//If the table is updated
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        //displaying failure
echo json_encode(array('ErrorMessage'=>'success')); 
}else{
    //displaying failure
    echo json_encode(array('ErrorMessage'=>'failure')); 
}
}else{
    //displaying failure if otp is not equal to the otp fetched from databse
    echo json_encode(array('ErrorMessage'=>'failure')); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

**Problem coming from**

```
//Creating the json object from the response
 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response); // print response.
```

- At first make sure your **`response`** is valid **`JSON`** or
  not.
- You should **`DEBUG`** your app. Add breakpoint  `JSONObject jsonResponse`

For **`valid JSON`** case you can follow [**`MByD's Answer`**.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10174938/3395198)

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {

        try {
            new JSONArray(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```