# Spring validate string value is a JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, validation, annotations

I have some value from my configuration file, that should be a JSON (which will be loaded as a String).

I'd like Spring to validate that this value is indeed a valid JSON before injecting it and throw an error else.

I've read about the validation annotations that exist, such as - `@NotNull`, `@Size`, `@Min`, `@Max`, `@Email`, `@NotEmpty` etc.

Is there any way to create a custom validator?

I want a validator that will attempt to convert the String to JSON, as in the following example: [How to convert jsonString to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-jsonstring-to-jsonobject-in-java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not provided by available validation annotations, therefore you have to go for a custom implementation. The task is divided into 2 simple steps:

**1. Is a given String is in the JSON format**

There are multiple libraries that are able to parse (therefore validate) a String whether follows the JSON syntax standard. Let's use my favourite GSON for example (there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-a-given-string-is-valid-json-in-java/10174938)). It depends on what library do you currently use:

```
String string = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
try {
    jsonParser.parse(string);       // valid JSON
} catch (JsonSyntaxException ex) { 
    /* exception handling */        // invalid JSON
}
```

**2. Custom validation annotation**

Start with providing a dependency enabling validations:

- groupId: `org.hibernate`
- artifactId: `hibernate-validator`

Create an annotation used for the validation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = JsonStringValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JsonString {
    String message() default "The String is not in JSON format";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

... and the validator handling the validation through the annotation:

```
public class JsonStringValidator implements ConstraintValidator<JsonString, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(JsonString jsonString) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String string, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // Use an implementation from step 1. A brief example:
        try {
            new JsonParser().parse(string);
            return true;                    // valid JSON, return true
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException ex) { 
            /* exception handling if needed */
        }
        return false;                       // invalid JSON, return false
    }
}
```

The usage is pretty straightforward:

```
@JsonString
private String expectedJsonString
```

This implementation is described in detail at [Baeldung's](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator).

Comment: I've created the annotation and the validator as you said, and tried using it as follows: `@JsonString @Value("${source.SomeJsonString}") private String someJsonString;` But it seems that nothing happens and the validator as not called..

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning it in the question. The problem with the solution in the link, is that I'm using my JSON string in multiple classes (it is injected into a few classes that are not related) and doing it so would force me to repeat the setters... Is there any other possible way?